A Christmas Word Search
The answer of this puzzle is a 6 letters word. (The whole puzzle was made by myself, easy but fun!)


Solving the word search (cute drawings by the way!) gives us

 
 where I've used different colours so that the words are hopefully better visible.

Completing the word search points us to the fact that

 the puzzle is actually a maze.


 So, after completing the maze,  we get the answer to be PRANCE.


I forgot to add, apologies if the formatting is a bit off, I've had to do this on my phone.

So quick！Actually, the clue you haven't figure out is like:10mm=1cm,100cm=1m,1000m=?.BTW, there's another hidden answer(3 4 3) waiting you to find!

Ah I did not notice the extra hidden answer bit of your comment, but I've updated the images with the clue I missed, thank you!

The other hidden answer involves the unused letters, I think.

I did consider that, but there are only 5 of them, I'm not sure what to do with those.
